# "The script don't inherit a native class that can manage a script."

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't know why but when I add my code in some object it gives this error, could someone help me?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Room : MonoBehaviour
{
   
   void OnTriggerStay2D (Collider2D other){

       if (other.CompareTag("Player")){
           CameraController.instance.SetPosition(new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y));
       }
       }
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's best to provide as much detail as possible when posting questions, in this case an image of the error could be helpful to others trying to help solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The generic reason for this is when you have a script file that is named different the class name. Ensure that your c# script file matches the name of your class. i.e. both should be `Room`.

Comment: they are exactly with the same name, I don't know what I did wrong

Comment: Do you have any other scripts that might not have the same name as their class?

Comment: What object are you attaching it to? Can you show us that object?

Comment: hello sorry for the delay, I solved my problem just by creating a new project, I don't know if it was a bug or something, but thanks

Comment: Thanks that was my issue! 

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Unity, when I tried to attach a script to an object.
After trying/isolating a lot of "google solutions" that didn't help in my case, like checking the name of the script and the class. (I already encountered that when I renamed a script earlier :P)
So to refocus, I first fixed an issue in another script(which had a typo), for another model in the same project.
After that the first thing I did was simply drag the script to the model again.. and it worked...

I'll add this option to my list of options when I'll encouter this “The script don't inherit a native class that can manage a script.” again...